# Batch compress .avi files with ffmpeg which contain previous date in their name

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, batch, compression

im trying to manage CCTV footage, and im trying to batch compress them with ffmpeg

So far i managed to come up with this command

```
ffmpeg -i "0515 210004.mp4" -b 200000  output.avi
```

But i need to do them all at once, **but** exclude the current date

So if today is 16.05, in my folder i have

```
"0515 210004.mp4"
"0515 220004.mp4"
"0515 230004.mp4"
"0516 000004.mp4"
"0516 010004.mp4"
```

And so on

I only need to convert those containing 0515, and everyday that number should increment, so on 17.05 i will need it to convert all the files with 0516 in them.

There are also sometimes files that will have **_1** in them, like "0515 180004_1.mp4"

(The 004 at the end is *always* there)

And i also need it to output it with the exact same name.

I see something like this

```
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -i "contains "%date% - 1day"" -b 200000 "oldfilename.avi"
```

I understand that this wont work, but lets call it my pseudo code

Do you have any ideas how i can accomplish my task?

Oh and im using Windows 7 x64

Also if you have any suggestions on ffmpeg part of this will be very happy to adjust my code

Comment: Key: __you have _fixed_ the first 4 digits and variable the rest of the name.__ Steps for your pseudo_code. 1. Build the strings for yesterday and tomorrow. 2. Select all the files that match the string of yesterday. 3. For each of them substitute the string of yesterday with the string of tomorrow in a `NewName` variable (and avi with mp4). 4. Output what you built. (after modify the output line with the ffmpeg one). Now you have only to search for each step the relative command(s)... `:-)`  After you can add check if the new filename exists...

Comment: The first 4 digits are fixed for only 1 day, the reason im creating this script is to automate it, so manually creating string names for everyday is not really an option. Or am i not understading you correctly?

Comment: I didn't suggest that (I abhor the simple idea to write it by hands `:-)`).  I only write one of the way to do it, in steps (_pseudocode_). When I said you to substitute, it means to let the script do it... with `date`, [`sed` equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe)... Even better with [string substitution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)...

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve using batch files. Think about what happens when the month changes. Getting yesterdays date is not simple. [how to get yesterday's date in a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11891335) will give you some ideas.

Comment: Silly me, seldom I forget cmd.exe can be so _primitive_. You can build with the date command of powershell or with [yesterday.bat](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#Yesterday),or install [gnu coreutils for windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html)...

Comment: Thank you for your powershell suggestions, i managed to come up with this

$a = get-date -format "MMdd"
$b = 1
$c = $a - $b
$d = $c.ToString("0000")
echo $d

Comment: @DavidPostill Did you get offended by the _primitive_ given  to the windows  `cmd.exe` ?  `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this

If anyone has code optimisation suggestions, will be very glad to incorporate them

Gets yesterdays date in MMdd  -> selects all files that begin with that -> compresses them using ffmpeg -> moves to another folder accroding to month  -> deletes source fules

```
$a = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMMM")
$d = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMdd")
$inProcessPath = "sourcepath"
$oldVideos = Get-ChildItem -Include @("$d *") -Path $inProcessPath -Recurse;

Set-Location -Path 'D:\ffmpeg\bin';

foreach ($oldVideo in $oldVideos) {
    $newVideo = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($oldVideo.FullName, '.avi')


    $ArgumentList = '-i "{0}" -b 200000 "{1}"' -f $oldVideo, $newVideo;


    Start-Process -FilePath "D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow;
}

Robocopy D:\Main\AdWords\ffmpeg\bin\ntv "D:\path\$a" "$d *.avi" /mov
get-childitem "sourcepath" -include "$d *.mp4" -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your question because you stated *"Do you have any ideas how I can accomplish my task?"* and you didn't ask for a code writing. I guess you want to learn. So this answer.

- Focus on which is the ***Key***, something that is unique and allow you to select only the items over which you have to operate. In this case you just said the **first four characters in the name** of the files in the current directory. Good.
  Good even more because they have the same length if is 1st of Jen. or 31 of Dec (even if you are not forced to use it.

Now you can write your batch script step by step:

1. Build the strings for yesterday and tomorrow <sup>[[d1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810544/get-date-in-yyyymmdd-format-in-windows-batch-file),[d2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945572/windows-batch-formatted-date-into-variable),[d3](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html)...]</sup>.

   ```
   $date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1); $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
   ```

   Note you have to modify here above for format and variable name, you need tomorrow too.
2. Select all the files that match the string of yesterday. (For and Yesterday variable)
3. For each <sup>[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file)]</sup> of them substitute (let the script to do it) the sub-string of yesterday with the sub-string of tomorrow, in a variable with a new name <sup>[[1](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)]</sup>. 
   Do not forget to change even `.mp4` with `.avi`...
4. Output the string that you built.
5. After that you are sure about your program, modify the output line with the ffmpeg one.

Now you have only to search for each step and tailor together the relative command(s)...

PS> In a second time you can enhance your script with check on the existence of the output file (you will not overwrite if it exists), with the number of file processed, with the good or bad exit of your script... In a second time.

Comment: Thank you, i will try that, so far i've come up with this in power shell to get the key 4 digits

$a = get-date -format "MMdd"
$b = 1
$c = $a - $b
$d = $c.ToString("0000")
echo $d

Comment: Follow the links (or search others) then do your attempts. More errors you will do and more you will learn. `:-)`